# How to loop through pages with particular template.php

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I would like to know how it is possible to loop through pages which have a particular template in Wordpress. I have a template `sale.php` which is assigned to some `pages` (not posts). I want to do following:

```
  <div class="test">
    <?php $recent = new WP_Query("template_name=sale"); while($recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post();?>
        <?php the_title(); ?>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
  </div>
```

obviously `template_name=sale` is not working. Is there something I can give as argument for the query to get only contents of all pages with a particular template.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use this line of code to loop through pages with particular template

`<?php is_page_template( $template ); ?>`  i mean

```
if ( is_page_template( 'sale.php' ) ) {
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
the_content();
endwhile;
 }  
 ?>
```

and i hope this code will work for you

Comment: Can you describe what problem is facing with my code